# How to Force HttpClient 3.0.1 to use TLS 1.3?

Tags: httpclient, tls1.2, java-7, apache-commons-httpclient, tls1.3

A legacy application built on Java7 with Apache Commons HttpClient 3.0.1 is calling Adobe Mixed Media Viewer API. As Adobe is going to stop supporting TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2, I wish to force the HttpClient to use TLS1.3. How to do the same?